# how to insert a php code in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm coding a php site to serve on file sharing . i had a problem with hiding the delete file option from users and showing it for site admin , the actual logged in user name is stored in a php session so hiding or showing the delete option will be used in php condition .
the problem is the php code never worked to add the "hidden" option on delete img tag .

in 1st step, js, jquery  and php code were separated in two files, so i had to copy jquery code in index.php (main page) since i had no other option to grab the logged in user from php session to js file.

```js
function render(data) {
  var scannedFolders = [],
    scannedFiles = [];

  if (scannedFiles.length) {
    scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {
      var fileSize = bytesToSize(f.size),
        name = escapeHTML(f.name),
        fileType = name.split('.'),
        icon = '<span class="icon file"></span>';

      fileType = fileType[fileType.length - 1];

      icon = '<span class="icon file f-' + fileType + '">.' + fileType + '</span>';
      var x = f.path.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
      var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.path+'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li><img src="assets/supp.png" height="42" width="42" id="logo" onclick=del("'+encodeURIComponent(x)+'")   if($_SESSION['username']!='info') {?> hidden <?php } ?>>');
      file.appendTo(fileList);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You've to wrap the PHP code within PHP tags.

Comment: where/which line in js need to place php code

Comment: @Teemu i added the <?php tag and still does not work ..

Comment: Please show also the rendered code of the `li`.

Comment: @Teemu                   <img src="assets/supp.png" height="42" width="42" id="logo" onclick="del(&quot;files%2FCARDIOLOGIE_B%2FFoxitPhantomPDF.exe&quot;)">

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username']!='info') echo 'hidden' ?>
```

You need to put your php code inside php tags. You had syntax errors in your example code.

That way if your `if` statement is true it will show the "hidden" parameter causing your html element to be invisible.

Comment: Better not put in the image at all, instead of only hiding it.

Comment: Well it will be hidden if the `if` is true. Otherwise it will not hide it since "hidden" won't be echoed. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Can you copy an paste your code to see how it looks now? Cause your problem was the syntax error at first place.

Comment: An image that is only hidden can easily be unhidden by any user. It's a start of a security risk. Now suppose the same sloppiness continues, and the Javascript `del()` function doesn't check that the user has permission to delete the file, then any user can use the delete option.

Comment: @pr1nc3   my code :                                                                                                                                var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.path+'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li><img src="assets/supp.png" height="42" width="42" id="logo" onclick=del("'+encodeURIComponent(x)+'")   <?php if($_SESSION['username']!='info') echo 'hidden' ?>>');